# Which error does one usually need to consider in numerical analysis?

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

When analyzing performance of a numerical method, I have considered and plotted $$\| x_n - x^* \|$$ where $x_n$ is the $n$-th iteration and $x^*$ is the true value (in our toy examples, it wasn't hard to find).

But my instructor told me that one is never supposed to know $x^*$. Thus, plotting it is pointless and I was supposed to plot 
$$\| x_n - x_{n-1} \|$$ instead.

Is that true? Are there any circumstances where plotting the first one is appropriate? Are there any circumstances where plotting the second one is pointless?

(In case it's relevant, the methods were fixed-point iteration, Newton's etc.)

Comment: When you are in an iterative process such as Newton, (or whatever) you don't know $x^*$. So, the second is what you have to consider.

Comment: If your goal is to evaluate the performance of the method, and you actually know $ x^*$ somehow, then $\| x_k - x^*\|$ seems like a good thing to plot. But, it might be interesting to try the method on some more challenging problems where the true $ x^*$ is not known. If you're solving a system of equations  $ f(x) = 0$, I think $\| f(x_k)\|$ seems like a good thing to plot when $ x^*$ is unknown.